# Multiple file upload in SugerCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am new to SugerCRM. Please tell me how can i upload multiple files in SugerCRM?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP and HTML there are many ways to upload files. But the basic file uploading process and be created by three types in PHP they are:

## Through FORM

You have to create the multiple files of File uploading in the Form. Each file uploaded would be processed individually by the program.

## Directory Selection

Second popular way is found is the directory uploading. Selection the directory and upload all the files in the directory one by one.

## Zip updloading

Third is zip all the files in single file and upload it then pragmatically process after unzip it and reading each file.

## SUGUR CRM

The file should look something like:

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

require_once('include/formbase.php');
require_once('modules/[MODULE TYPE]/config.php');
require_once('include/SugarFields/SugarFieldHandler.php');

$focus = new [MODULE TYPE]();
$focus = populateFromPost('', $focus);

if(!$focus->ACLAccess('Save')){
    ACLController::displayNoAccess(true);
    sugar_cleanup(true);
}

//SOME CODE TO CONVERT TO BINARY AND THEN STORE VALUE INTO FIELD NAME USING
// $focus->[fieldName] = outputFromBinaryConversion($_POST['theFileField']);
// That would store the blob into the existing _cstm table
// --OR, you would get the id of the saved module using $return_id = $focus->id;
// and use the id to link to the blob stored in another (unsupported) table.


$focus->save();
```

I hope that clarifies your direction a bit, but I would really recommend looking at using the existing document handling class, as it will be much cleaner and quicker to implement.

Answer (score 0):

The documents module can be overkill if you just want a simple upload field. Coding a solution is possible, but can take quite a bit of time if you want to do it right (support multiple files, modules, etc). There is this solution that lets you add as many file fields as you need: https://www.sugaroutfitters.com/addons/file-upload-module

Answer (score 0):

It's a very long procedure, to brief it

1. Add multiple file upload feature of JavaScript through custom code.
2. Create one custom module that will create relation with your current module and new module (that will save all documents uploaded).
3. Create logic hook that will save the uploaded files in upload directory and relationship between these modules.

Detail post referred on

http://www.technologyworkshops.net/php/custom-multiple-file-upload-sugar-crm-t129.html

I can help you with editing, removing current files, listing and subpanel view. if you want i can share it here.